# How to fix add to cart button not working in magento after calling external .js file

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.7

I'm having issues with the magento add to cart button not working after I include an external .js file. The .js file is being included in the footer and is part of a newsletter sign-up form hosted by GoDaddy. The strange thing is, the button was working fine until a couple of days ago. I didn't make any changes so my only conclusion is that GoDaddy changed something in this script that is now causing it to conflict.

I've uploaded a copy of the conflicting script to https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5944682

I did a few searches here and see several previous posts with a similar issue, and all recommend using jQuery.noconflict(). I tried several methods of using this but all had no effect. I'm am new to jQuery however, so I may not have implemented this correctly.

Is there any way to get this script working with my store again? And ideas would be a big help!

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error that comes up on your Javascript console?

Please make sure your Javascript loads in the following order:

1. Prototype
2. jQuery
3. jQuery.noconflict()
4. jQuery plugins

Also make sure to replace $ with jQuery (eg. `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...`) where there are conflicts with Prototype.

Comment: I'm actually not receiving any errors in the console, which I did think was strange. I'll verify everything is loading the correct order.

Comment: @Trevor surely there is an error each time you press the add to cart button. Also try disable your current theme to fall back to the base theme and see how that goes.

Comment: I am receiving an error but, I thought this was an unrelated issue.
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method        'flexslider'
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i`

Comment: @Trevor sounds to me like Flexslider plugin is trying to load itself before jQuery does.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to load jQuery at very top i.e. before prototype and write `jQuery.noconflict()` at the end of your jquery file. 
Then initialize your jQuery code with `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`.